# ProgressDialog inside setOnClickListener is not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show progress dialog inside onclicklistener, while calling another function to do some calculations. this function is in another class.
Here is my code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Game.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading)); // Setting Message
                    progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.checking)); // Setting Title
                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner

                    progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

then I am calling another function:

```
Solver.dosolve();
```

the above function should fill in some elements in array (solved_array). then I am doing an action to this array. ( this all takes about 3 seconds).

```
solved_array.remove(solved_array.size() - 1);
```

then dismissing the progress dialog:

```
    if(progressDialog!= null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

testing results:

1. If I didn't dismiss the progress dialog, then it's showing well all time (but for sure the app hangs as setCancelable(false);
2. If I didn't dismiss  the progress dialog, then it's not showing at all.

Your suggestions to show the progress dialog while calling another function are highly appreciated.

Comment: you should go for multithreading. google "AsyncTask".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a new thread to run your function.

```
     Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


            //update UI  show dialog for example
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.show;
                }
            });

            try {
            //simulating expensive function
            System.out.println("function started");

                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("function finished");
            //update the UI
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss;
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

use `t.start()` and `t=null` to start and cancel your thread.

you also can go for [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I am checking threat, Checked AsyncTask before but crash the app.

Comment: you should figure out where is the problem. AsyncTask crashes the app doesn't mean to give it up.

Comment: both Threat & AsyncTask are giving same error : has leaked window DecorView. I am going to google it and hope to find a solution. Thanks Bishoy very much

Comment: Bishoy, one question please. When trying to start the threat to the second time i get " Thread already started" . I tried to stop it before starting again t.stop(). but fails. any suggestions? thx